Printer not showing in chromium in Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I installed recently Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on a new machine and I can not see the local printer in chromium (default snap version). The local printer is available in others non snap applications and even in firefox that is also a snap.
My snap list:
Name                       Version          Rev    Tracking       Publisher      Notes
bare                       1.0              5      latest/stable  canonical✓     base
chromium                   128.0.6613.119   2943   latest/stable  canonical✓     -
core22                     20240823         1612   latest/stable  canonical✓     base
cups                       2.4.10-1         1058   latest/stable  openprinting✓  -
firefox                    130.0-2          4848   latest/stable  mozilla✓       -
gnome-42-2204              0+git.510a601    176    latest/stable  canonical✓     -
gtk-common-themes          0.1-81-g442e511  1535   latest/stable  canonical✓     -
onlyoffice-desktopeditors  8.1.1            196    latest/stable  onlyoffice✓    -
snapd                      2.63             21759  latest/stable  canonical✓     snapd

What i see in firefox:

Any idea on how to fix the issue in chromium official snap version?

Snap apps are sandboxed, and many things don't work there. Duplicate of: How to install Chromium browser without snap or flatpak in Ubuntu 24.04?.

I want to keep on with the official chromium version of Ubuntu. I will use the workaround you propose only if there is no way to have the local printer working with the snap version. But as it works with firefox I'm confident there is a solution to have it work with chromium.
